# Search function with one to one relationship in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I would like to make a simple search function for my table. This table get the data from two mssql [Addresses] and [Companies] tables. The tables have one to one relationship.

```
class Addresses extends Model
{
    protected $table = "Addresses";
    protected $primaryKey = 'adress';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function scopeSearchAddress($query, $searchTerm)
    {
        return $query->where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')
                     ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')
                     ->orWhere('street', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
    }

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Company::class, 'adress');
    }
```

The relationship is one address one company.
The first table adress have name, street, city columns and the second table have compName, compType.

```
class Company extends Model
{
    protected $table = "Company";
    protected $primaryKey = 'Adresse';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Addresses::class, 'adress');
    }

}
```

this are the two models. The controller look like this:

```
class AddressesController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $searchTerm = $request->input('searchTerm');

        $addresses = Addresses::whereHas('compan', function($query) {
             $query->where('compType','D');
        })->orderBy('Name')
        ->searchAddress($searchTerm)
        ->paginate(60);
        return view('asdress.index', compact('addresses', 'searchTerm'));
    }
}
```

i can search after the first table columns (city, name, street). but how can i search after the second table columns like the compName.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `orWhere` for every company table field you want to search on in `whereHas` closure.

```
$searchTerm = $request->input('searchTerm');

$addresses = Addresses::whereHas('company', function($query) use($searchTerm){
     $query->where('compType','D')

     //append other where queries on company fields
     ->orWhere('company_table_field_name', $searchTerm);
});
```

Comment: Hello you forgot the use($searchTerm) after the function but this is also not working.

Comment: @GregOstry thanks for pointing that out... my bad... edited my answer